# Entity Framework Constructor Injection in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework in ASP.net Core, I have many classes where I am using an instance of the `DbContext` to interact with the database, I'm using constructor injection in every class and controller but I feel like a trained monkey repeating that code all the time, maybe I'm doing this the wrong way and there are better ways to do this. I'm feeling tired to write again and again the same code for every controller and every class I'm using an instance of `DbContext`..

`Startup` class:

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.Configure<DBConnection> Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        }
```

That code is fine, no problem at all, but now: Do I need to repeat the code below for every class and controller?? I know I have not read a lot yet about services and that I might be losing something obvious, I'm just copying the constructors, but in some classes where I need instances I need to add a field named `_connectionAccessor` of type `IOptions<DBConnection>`:

```
      public FirstController(IOptions<DBConnection> connectionsAccessor)
            {
                _context = new DataContext(connectionsAccessor);
                _connectionAccessor = connectionsAccessor;
            }
     public EmailController(IOptions<DBConnection> connectionsAccessor)
            {
                this.ctx = new DataContext(connectionsAccessor);
                _connectionAccessor = connectionsAccessor;
            }
     public MyRepository(IOptions<DBConnection> connectionsAccessor)
            {
                _context = new DataContext(connectionsAccessor);  
                _connectionAccessor = connectionsAccessor;      
            }
```

And like that for every controller and class, and I have a lot of classes and controllers, is this the only way?

Oh this is my `DbContext` class:

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(IOptions<DBConnection> connectionsAccessor)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionsAccessor.Value.MySQLContext;                   
        }
```

Comment: Why did you undo my edit?

Comment: @DavidG I'm sorry, I was editing at the same time and pressed save edits didn't realized :(

Comment: I fixed all your code formatting :)

Comment: thanks I apologize with you :)

Comment: Could you use a base controller class?